# Will I be able to use the Unifix tool to repair a floating floor that was glued on the edges?

Tags: flooring

Our engineered floating floor was installed by a contractor who glued the edges. We now have some damaged boards in the center of the kitchen that I would like to replace.
 I have seen the Unifix tool online and it looks pretty easy to use, but I don't know if the boards will separate since they have been glued.
 Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: Wow, that is a whole lot of money for a piece of metal.

Comment: That is a lot of money for a piece of metal, but I figured it would be worth it if it made the job easier. I guess I have to go the hard route. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

It's not fun or easy, but it can be done.  Good answer was provided here [How can I replace a board in floating wood floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25608/how-can-i-replace-a-board-in-floating-wood-floor):

From the previous answer:

> You'd have to treat it like a hardwood floor t&g repair:
>   Run a circular saw down one side, staying away from seam at least the thickness of the tongue, with depth set to board thickness.
>   Repeat #1 along the other side.
>   Connect the top and bottom cuts across the board, either with a chisel or OMT (Oscillating multi tool).
>   Carefully cut into corners to free the 4 border pieces, as necessary. They may just pry out.
>   Trim the bottom half of the groove off. (I like to use a table saw and fence). You should be able to wedge it in with the tongue intact, though a small bottom bevel might assist it.
>   Sparingly glue along edges of existing tongues and the new board edges and weight it down, as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the tongue and grove were properly glued I doubt banging on them will separate the boards without causing more harm.  The glued joint is going to be pretty strong and it will tear the wood, not just at the board but the entire seam you are banging against.

It will be better to use the more common method of just cutting the damaged board out and replacing with a new board.  If you search online there should be some great tutorials for how to do it.